# Cropping images with Flutter image package is not working

Tags: flutter, dart

I try to crop images in a Flutter application with the `image` package in a for loop.

**More Details:**
I have a list of many images. I try to figure out the trim data of the first image and apply it to all other images. For this I follow this official tutorial from `image` package: https://github.com/brendan-duncan/image/wiki/Examples **("Load a directory of images, auto-trim the first image, and apply the trim to all subsequent images.")**

**This is my `for` loop:

```
for (var i = 0; i < allPictures.length; i++) {
  var file = File(allPictures[i].path);

  print("Start Cropping");

  var decodedImage =
      image.decodeImage(File(file.path).readAsBytesSync());

  print("Decoded Image: $decodedImage");

  if (decodedImage == null) {
    print("Continue");
    continue;
  }
  if (trimRect == null) {
    print("Is null");
    trimRect =
        image.findTrim(decodedImage, mode: image.TrimMode.transparent);
  }

  image.copyCrop(
      decodedImage, trimRect[0], trimRect[1], trimRect[2], trimRect[3]);

  print("Cropped!");

  File(allPictures[i].path).writeAsBytesSync(
      image.encodeNamedImage(decodedImage, allPictures[i].path));

}
```

**The problem**

My for loop is hanging after the first index. So that `image.copyCrop(decodedImage, trimRect[0], trimRect[1], trimRect[2], trimRect[3]);` was never reached. What could be the issue there?

**This is the console output:**

```
flutter: Start Cropping
flutter: Decoded Image: Instance of 'Image'
flutter: Is null
flutter: Cropped!
flutter: Start Cropping
flutter: Decoded Image: Instance of 'Image'
```

And I get the error: `flutter: RangeError (index): Index out of range: index should be less than 899072: 899072`

Comment: What happens if you step through it with a debugger?

Comment: I get the error `flutter: RangeError (index): Index out of range: index should be less than 899072: 899072`

Comment: My guess then is that the clip rect is outside the bounds of one of your images. Are your images the same size?

Comment: No, absolutely different because the images are images uploaded from users... and they can have every size..

Comment: Then I'm more confident that that is the problem. You are basing the crop size on the first image, but what if the first image is 1000x800 and its calculated clip rect is `Rect.fromLTWH(100, 100, 900, 900)`, then the second image is only 200x300? That clip rect is several times bigger than the entire second image.

Comment: I understand... thank you! What could I do to prevent this? Maybe scale all other images to the min-dimensions of the first? What do you would recommend?

Comment: I recommend not using the same crop pattern for images that can be vastly different dimensions and aspect ratios.

Comment: @asored Hi did you solve your problem? I am experiencing the same issue

Comment: I did not crop the images with the data of the first because the dimensions can be very different. I'm going another way. I needed this for a video which I create with `ffmpeg` and my solution was to crop the video itself, not the images. Sorry that I don't have a solution for you:/

Answer (score 0):

**try this may be your problem solve**

> for (var i = 0; i <= allPictures.length-1; i++)

Answer (score -2):

Try this

```
for (var i = 0; i < allPictures.length; ++i)
```